# How to use Axios interceptors with useSWR to revalidate access/refresh JWTs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query, swr

I was thinking about switching to useSWR in my Nextjs project from just plain Axios, but I stumbled upon an issue with the authentication of my app. It uses JWT authentication where the refresh token is stored as a httpOnly cookie on the client, and the access token is stored in memory on the client.

Basically:

when a request to an endpoint which requires authentication returns a 403 status, a response interceptor that has been applied to the axios instance attempts to refresh the users tokens using the refresh token. It also applies a new header to the request to imply it has already been sent, as to prevent an infinite loop if the server again returns a 403 status. If the server returns with the new access token, then we append that to the Authorization header on the original request and retry it.

This is the hook I use for this logic:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { useRefreshToken } from "./useRefreshToken";
import { privateAxios, publicAxios } from "@/api/axios";
import { useAccessTokenState } from "@/store/memory";

export const usePrivateAxios = () => {
  const refresh = useRefreshToken();
  const accessToken = useAccessTokenState();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Append the access token to the request
    const requestInterceptor = privateAxios.interceptors.request.use(
      (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
        config.headers = config.headers ?? {};
        if (!config.headers["Authorization"]) {
          config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${accessToken.value}`;
        }
        return config;
      },
      (error) => Promise.reject(error)
    );

    // Refresh the access token if it has expired, and retry the original request
    const responseInterceptor = privateAxios.interceptors.response.use(
      (response: AxiosResponse) => response,
      async (error) => {
        const prevRequest = error?.config;
        if (error?.response?.status === 403 && !prevRequest?.sent) {
          prevRequest.sent = true;
          const newAccessToken = await refresh();
          prevRequest.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`;
          return privateAxios(prevRequest);
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

    return () => {
      privateAxios.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptor);
      privateAxios.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptor);
    };
  }, [accessToken, refresh]);

  return privateAxios;
};
```

Now my question is how would you go about implementing this using SWR? Would it be valid to just do like this?

```
const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR("/api/users", usePrivateAxios());
```

It doesn't seem to complain or anything, but is it weird to be passing in the custom hook like this? And how will useSWR behave if the refresh fails? Anything else I didn't think about?

Answer (score 0):

now u have solution ? i doing same ur case. I think still use Axios like a fetch with useSWR.

i will config base axios with interceptor. and after use this config when call api like this.

```
export const request = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
  // withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
    accept: 'application/json',
  },
});
request.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const token = storageService.getItem('accessToken');
      if (token) {
        config.headers = {
          ...config.headers,
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        };
      }
    }

    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

and i will config with every service like this

```
class UserSevice {
    route: string;
    KEY_USER: string;
    constructor() {
        this.route = '/users';
        this.KEY_USER = '';
    }
    getKeyUser(username: string) {
        this.KEY_USER = `${this.route}/${username}`;
        return this.KEY_USER;
    }

    async getUserInfo(path: string) {
        const result = await httpRequest.get(path);
        return result.data;
    }
}
```

and when i use with useSWR,  i use like this

```
 const keyUser = userService.getKeyUser(user as string);
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useSWR(keyUser, userService.getUserInfo, {
    revalidateOnMount: true,
  });
```

do u think my handle correct ?

Answer (score 0):

> but is it weird to be passing in the custom hook like this?

You aren't passing the hook, you are passing a fetcher that was returned by calling the hook.

> And how will useSWR behave if the refresh fails?

The default behaviour is to retry failing requests some number of times, but you can configure it differently.

> Anything else I didn't think about?

Not related to SWR, but you don't seem to be updating `accessToken` when you refresh, so future requests will use still use the old token.